# Trouble with Regex (.NET) - Finding all groups of lines before a string

Tags: .net, regex

I have a long file and it contains text that looks like  (repeating blocks of different text separated by ***END***)

```
text text text text
df093nr v39rkf 
.o  dfwe

g9

 ***END***
text text text text
df093nr v39rkf 
.o  dfwe

g9

 ***END***
```

I'm trying to capture the groups of text to each string ***END***

I can't get a regex that works 
So far I'm at this one

```
(?m).*\n(?:.*\n)+?\s*[*][*][*]END[*][*][*]
```

But the problem is it captures everything all the way until the very end (one match)
Any suggestions would be helpful, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the matched group from index 1

```
([\s\S]*?)(?:\r?\n\s+\*\*\*END\*\*\*)
```

Here is [regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/iT4eX9/2) and tested at [regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5b%5cs%5cS%5d*%3f)(%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%5cs%2b%5c*%5c*%5c*END%5c*%5c*%5c*)&i=text+text+text+text%0d%0adf093nr+v39rkf+%0d%0a.o++dfwe%0d%0a%0d%0ag9%0d%0a%0d%0a+***END***%0d%0atext+text+text+text%0d%0adf093nr+v39rkf+%0d%0a.o++dfwe%0d%0a%0d%0ag9%0d%0a%0d%0a+***END***)

---

String literals for use in programs:

```
@"([\s\S]*?)(?:\r?\n\s+\*\*\*END\*\*\*)"
```

Comment: why do you use [\s\S] rather than .

Comment: @erotavlas to match **multiple lines** till `***END***` is not found.